# replacing elements of an array change by change

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, replace

I'm trying to do some basics concerning an array of elements, specifically characters. My question is, how do I get the program to print my changes one by one? for example (I do not want my output going from "moon" to "mOOn" in one instance, but from "moon" to "mOon" to "mOOn", like that. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Practice 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
 {  
    String array[] = {"uuuuuuuupppppppssssssssss"};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(array[i] = array[i].replace('p', 'P'));
        //trying to print each change here
    }
 }
}
```

Thanks again!

EDIT/Update: I got the output to get the loop right, but the output is still not what I want (basically output: uPPPPPPS, uPPPPPPs, uPPPPPs, etc until the length of p ends). Any hints on what I could do? Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String array = "uuuuuuuupppppppssssssssss";
  System.out.println(array);
  char[] chars = array.toCharArray(): //converted 

  for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
         if (chars[i] == 'p') {
                System.out.println(array.replace('p', 'P'));
            }
      }
 }
```

Comment: You would have to make your own replace method and in their print it out. If you use the `String` class `.replace` you can't print the string each and every time that letter gets replaced

Comment: Create `char[]`, iterate over it and each time you find character you want to change do so and print current sate of this array.

Comment: What is the point of having array for one element `String array[] = {"uuuuuuuupppppppssssssssss"};`?

Comment: So make a replace method and also change my array to char? I tried that but then it says that char cannot be dereferenced

Comment: Each time you look at a character, convert it to uppercase (look at the javadoc for the Character class) and then set array to a new String made up of the current chars array. (Also, don't call your string 'array' as that's misleading.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String array = "uuuuuuuupppppppssssssssss";
    System.out.println(array);

    while ( array.contains("p") )
    {
        array = array.replaceFirst("p", "P");
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```